# Django: Importing a view from another app

Tags: python, django

I have a project and an app. I am trying to use the urls.py in the project to activate a view held in the app.

The error message: import homepage.index
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'homepage.index'

In the project urls.py I have this import statement:

## project/urls.py

```
from homepage.views import index
```

Then in the project's urls.py, the urlpatterns[] array includes this 
reference to the app's view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', homepage.views.index, name='index'),
]
```

## homepage/views.py

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("My Homepage")
```

Where might be the error?

Answer (score 2):

You are not importing correctly. Change

```
url(r'^$', homepage.views.index, name='index'),
```

to

```
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework  that is written in python, there is no magic involved.You are specifying full path to your view in `urls.py`

```
# here the view is available as index
from homepage.views import index
# so reference the view as index
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
```

if you need to reference will full namespace,

```
# here the view can be imported as you intented
import homepage
url(r'^$', homepage.views.index, name='index'),
```

**Things to be noted**
`ModuleNotFound` is raised when the module refered is not available, 
in this case `python` will try to use `homepage` module but it is not available in the current context.
`ImportError` is raised when the refered attribute or module is not available in already imported module or when you are using `from module import x`.

```
>>> from os import wow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'wow'
```