# django 2.2.5 import url from one app to another app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I would like to use the url from products app (products/urls.py) inside of search app url (search/urls.py) to search for items/products using search bar. I've attempted this example on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/) but it's importing a view to url in the same app, and I've also attempted [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336920/django-importing-a-view-from-another-app) but it looks to be a solution for an older version of django but i am using the latest version of django at time time 2.2.5.

The error message I am receiving in terminal is coming from search/urls.py:

> path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
>   AttributeError: module 'search.views' has no attribute
>   'ProductListView'

I understand search.views does not have an attribute "ProductListView" but, products.views does, which is why i'm trying to import products.views in search/urls.py.

products/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .import views

app_name = "products"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    re_path(r'^products/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.ProductDetailSlugView.as_view(), name='detail'),

]
```

search/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from products.views import ProductListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),

]
```

ecommerce/urls.py (main app)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

# from products.views import ProductDetailView

from .views import home, about, contact

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', contact, name='contact'),
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls'), name='login'),
    path('register/', include('allauth.urls'), name='register'),
    path('products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    path('search/', include('search.urls', namespace='search')),

    # path('', include('products.urls'), name='products-featured'),
    # path('', include('products.urls'), name='featured-details'),
    # path('', include('products.urls'), name='featured-slug-details'),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Alasdair has shown you the correct import, but why are you doing this? ProductListView already has a URL in products/urls. Why do you want it in search as well?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo `from .views import * as views` is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
from products.views import ProductListView
```

Therefore you should use `ProductListView`, not `views.ProductListView`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    ...
]
```

Note you can remove the `from .import views` import unless you are using `views` somewhere else in `search/urls.py`

An alternative is to use import as, so that you can import multiple `views.py` from different apps in the same module:

```
from products import views as product_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
]
```

Comment: that did the trick along with including app_name='search' in search/urls.py. thanks